# Prove shuffled sequence $\{x_i, y_i\}$ converges $\iff \lim x_n = \lim y_n$ (Abbott p 49 q2.3.5)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Let $(x_{n})$ and $(y_{n})$ be given. Define $(z_{n})$ to be the shuffled sequence $(x_{1}.y_{1},\ x_{2},\ y_{2},\ x_{3},\ldots,x_{n}, y_{n},\ldots)$ . Prove that $(z_{n})$ is conv ergent  $\iff (x_{n})$ and $(y_{n})$ are both convergent $\backslash $ with $ \lim x_{n}=\lim y_{n}$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary. Let's call the limit that $(z_{n})$ converges to $L$. Then we must find a natural number $N$ such that when $n \geq N$, then $|y_{\gamma 1}-L|<\epsilon$. Because $(z_{n})\rightarrow L$, we can pick $N_1$ so that $| z_{n}-L|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N_1$. Because $y_{n}=z_{2N}$, it certainly follows that $|y_{n}-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\geq N_1.$ A similar argument holds for the $(x_{n})$ sequence, because $x_n = z_{2N - 1}$.

> **1.** Why did solution capitalize in $y_{n}=z_{2\color{red}{N}}$? Is it at fault to write lowercase :  $y_{n}=z_{2\color{red}{n}}$ for all $n \in N$? By the agency of the definition, $y_n := z_{even}$ and $x_n := z_{odd}$.

$(<=)$ Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Again, let $L$ be the common limit of $(x_{N})$ and $(y_{n})$ . We need to show that there exists an $N$ such that when $n\geq N$, then $|z_{N}-L|<\epsilon$. Choose $N_1$ so $|x_{n}-L|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N_{1}$, and choobe $N_{2}$ such that $|y_{n}-L|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N_{2}$. Finally, let $N =\max\{\color{magenta}{2}N_{1},\color{magenta}{2}N_{2}\}$. Then  from the construction of the sequence $(z_{n})$, it follows $|z_{n}-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $n \geq N$.

> **2.** When I first did this, I picked $N =\max\{N_{1},N_{2}\}$. Is this faultless? Why do we need the $\color{magenta}{2}$?
>   **3.** Please explain 'from the construction of the sequence'? I don't understand 'construction' here. How does convergence of $\{z_n\}$ follow?

@HagenvonEitzen Sorry...I don't understand your answers. What does 'yes' mean for **1.** ?
For **2.**, is it at fault to exclude the $\color{magenta}{2}$ ? Why use $\color{magenta}{2}$?

Comment: Is $y_{\gamma1}$, $x_{Ti}$, $y_{rl}$ a consequnce of bad OCR and should be $y_n$, $x_n$, $y_n$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes thanks. please rectify any other errors in my question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. You want to show $|z_n-L|<\epsilon$ for $n>N$. By the way $z_n$ is defined, you have either $z_n=x_k$ with $n=2k-1$, or $z_n=y_k$ with $n=2k$.
   So to make the conclusion, you'd want $|x_k-L|<\epsilon$ and $|y_k-L|<\epsilon$, respectively. You can do so if $k>N_1$ and $k>N_2$, respectively, i.e. $k>\max\{N_1,N_2\}$. If $n>2\max\{N_1,N_2\}$, this works.